# Fill the numbers between two columns in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with below columns:

```
id  start  end
1   101    101
2   102    104
3   108    109
```

I want to fill the gaps between start and end with additional rows, so the output may look like this:

```
id  number
1    101
2    102
2    103
2    104
3    108
3    109
```

Is there anyway to do it in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with `range` and flattening for list of tuples, last use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
zipped = zip(df['id'], df['start'], df['end'])

df = pd.DataFrame([(i, y) for i, s, e in zipped for y in range(s, e+1)],
                   columns=['id','number'])
print (df)
   id  number
0   1     101
1   2     102
2   2     103
3   2     104
4   3     108
5   3     109
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure pandas solution but performance-wise, @jaezrael's solution would be better,

```
df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.arange(x.start, x.end + 1)), axis = 1)\
.stack().astype(int).reset_index()\
.drop('level_1', 1)\
.rename(columns = {0:'Number'})

    id  Number
0   1   101
1   2   102
2   2   103
3   2   104
4   3   108
5   3   109
```