# adding rows based on values of other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list (in a dataframe) that looks like this:

```
oddnum = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 23]
```

I want to create a new list that looks like this:

```
newlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 23]
```

1. I want to test if the distance between two numbers is 2 (if oddnum[index+1]-oddnum[index] == 2)
2. If the distance is 2, then I want to add the number following oddnum[index] and create a new list (oddnum[index] + 1)
3. If the distance is greater than two, keep the list as is

I keep getting key error because (I think) the list runs out of [index] and [index+1] no longer exists once it reaches the end of the list. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass errors, the best method is to use `try` and `except` conditions. Here's my code:

```
oddnum = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 23]
res = [] # The new list
for i in range(len(oddnum)):
    res.append(oddnum[i]) # Append the first value by default
    try: # Tries to run the code
        if oddnum[i] +  2 == oddnum[i+1]: res.append(oddnum[i]+1) # Appends if the condition is met
    except: pass # Passes on exception (in our case KeyError)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to apply the same logic if I have two lists? For example:

list1 = [5, 7, 9, 11, 17]
list2 = [7, 9, 11, 13, 21]

(assuming that values in list 2 are always greater than values in list 1)

fill in between two values in each list (list2[index]-list1[index])

new_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]

Comment: Two lists as in? Could you show an example?

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960867/fill-the-numbers-between-two-columns-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: Oh, I thought you just want for one list as written. np

Answer (score 1):

```
oddnum = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 23]

new_list = []

for pos, num in enumerate(oddnum):

    new_list.append(num)
    
    try:

        if num-oddnum[pos+1] in [2, -2]:

            new_list.append(num+1)
    except:

     pass
        
print(new_list)
```

Use `try:` `except:` to prevent exceptions popping up and ignore it